# Basic finite dimensional distribution question

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around the basic idea of a finite dimensional distribution.  Suppose $(\Omega, \Bbb P, \mathcal{F})$ is a probability space.

Let $(X_{t})_{t \geq 0}$ be a stochastic process, i.e., $X_{t}: \Omega \to \Bbb R $ is a random variable for each $t$.

Let $\mu_{t}$ be the distribution measure of $X_{t}$ on $\mathcal{B}(\Bbb R)$, i.e., $\mu_{t}(A) = \Bbb P(X^{-1}(A))$ for each $A \in \mathcal{B}(\Bbb R)$.

Given $t_{1}, t_{2}, \dots, t_{n} \geq 0$, we can talk about the *finite dimensional distribution* of the vector $(X_{t_{1}},X_{t_{2}},\dots,X_{t_{n}})$.  Specifically, this is the measure $\mu$ defined by:

$$\mu(D) = \Bbb P \{ \omega \in \Omega \mid (X_{t_{1}}(\omega), X_{t_{2}}(\omega), \dots, X_{t_{n}}(\omega)) \in D \} $$ where $D \subseteq \Bbb R^{n}$ is a Borel set.  So $\mu$ is a measure on $\mathcal{B}(\Bbb R^{n})$.

For some reason, I'm having trouble understanding what this measure is doing.  For example, what if we have a measurable rectangle $A_{1} \times \cdots \times A_{n}$?  My gut is telling me that the measure of this is just the product of the distribution measures, i.e., $\mu(A_{1} \times \cdots \times A_{n}) = \mu_{t_{1}}(A_{1})\mu_{t_{2}}(A_{2}) \cdots \mu_{t_{n}}(A_{n})$.  Is that right?  Can anyone give me more information about this distribution?  I'm very new to this material.

Comment: If the $X_{t_k}$ are independent that would be correct, but that was not part of the hypotheses...

Comment: @copper.hat Thanks for the observation.  Can you give me any additional insight into this measure?

Comment: Not really. I think of it as 'sampling', but that doesn't add insight.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A finite-dimensional distribution is just the joint distribution of a random vector. You pick various time points $t_1,t_2,\ldots,t_n$, observe the stochastic process at those time points, and ask yourself "what's the distribution of this random vector?"

To define a FDD it is sufficient to specify the joint distribution on rectangles $A_1\times A_2\times \cdots\times A_n$ (as you've suggested), or  on products of half-infinte intervals $(-\infty,a_1]\times(-\infty,a_2]\times\cdots\times(-\infty,a_n]$ (to generalize the one-dimensional CDF of a scalar random variable). In general, these joint distributions won't correspond to product measure unless the selected time points yield independent variables; typically you get a joint distribution of correlated random variables. For example, if the stochastic process is Brownian motion, then the finite-dimensional distributions will be *correlated* multivariate gaussian.

The simplest finite-dimensional distribution occurs when $n=1$: you get just the distribution of $X_t$, the process observed at a single time point.

Comment: What is a "joint distribution" of a vector?  I think if I understood that, it would really help me, but I'm not sure what it is.

Comment: If the random vector is $d$-dimensional, its joint distribution is the probability distribution on $\mathbb R^d$ of the values of the vector. You can usually specify the joint distribution using a $d$-dimensional density function, if the vector is continuous. Usually we say "joint" for the distribution of the whole vector, to distinguish it from the "marginal" distribution of each component of the vector.

Comment: Example: To specify the joint distribution on half-infinite intervals you need to report $P(X_{t_1}\le  a_1, X_{t_2}\le a_2, \ldots, X_{t_n}\le a_n)$ for all choices of $(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$.

Comment: I want to add my thoughts about this and see if you agree with them before I take any further action on this question.  Here is my (potentially incorrect) idea:  The reason we call the measure $\mu(A) = \Bbb P(X^{-1}(A))$ the *distribution* of the random variable $X$ is because it gives us information on where $X$ is "likely" to $B$.  In other words, it tells us how likely $X$ will fall within the set $A$, so that if we somehow were to represent all possible locations of $X$, we would get a picture of how $X$ is "distributed" throughout $\Bbb R$.  Is the in any way a correct interpretation...

Comment: ...of distribution?  If not, can you give me a better intuitive explanation of what a distribution is?

Comment: Yes, your intuition is correct. $P(X^{-1}(A))$ is the probability that $X$ falls within set $A$. The distribution is the collection of all such probabilities for all possible $A$.